# How can we identify the View of Selected Item of Picker in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

How can we identify the View of **Selected Item** of **Picker** in Xamarin?

We have one view i.e. **SearchPage.xaml**. And one ViewModel of this view i.e. **SearchPageVm.cs**. We have multiple Picker and controls are available in Search Page.

We have five Tabs i.e. Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4, Tab5. And each Tab contains the Search Page View. Kindly note here that we are creating a single instance of Search Page view model and the same instance is binded to each new instance of SearchPageView that is being used in different tabs.

If Tab1 is selected and the user selects an item of Picker1. The SelectItem property bound to Picker1 is available in SearchPageVm. We are getting 5 calls and we are unable to identify, which View is calling to this.

We want to perform an action but only once.

**Sample Code:**

**SearchPage.xaml**

```
 <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
                         xmlns:SearchVm="clr-namespace:MyApplication.ViewModel;assembly=MyApplication"
                         x:Class="MyApplication.Views.SearchPage"
                         BindingContext="{x:Static SearchVm:CommonDataCache.SearchPageVmInstance}">

                <ScrollView Orientation="Both" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0,0,10,0">
                    <StackLayout x:Name="ControlStackLeft">
                        <customControls:SearchPageGrid
                            VisibleOnPages="Tab1,Tab2,Tab3,Tab4,Tab5">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Item1" />
                            <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Item1List}"
                                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem1,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </customControls:SearchPageGrid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
```

**SearchPageVm.cs:**

```
    private string _selectedItem1;

    public string SelectedItem1
    {
        get => _selectedItem1;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem1));
            if (SelectedItem1 != null)
                //Perform some Action
        }
    }
```

**Tab1.xaml:**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0">
            <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal"
                        IsClippedToBounds="True">
                <views:SearchPage x:Name="SearchView" />
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't unterstand "We are getting 5 calls". The setter of SelectedItem1 is called 5 times when u pick something? Other than that, I think you could check the current page you are on, everytime the setter is called. But i think its a little hacky

Comment: @Csharpest: "We are getting 5 calls" means when we select an item from Picker1, the SelectedItem1 setter calls 5 times.And we have value for "Current Page".

Comment: Without seeing a lot more code, it would be difficult to figure out what is happening. something in your design seems off. Sounds like multiple things are bound to the same property and some kind of loop is being triggered between all of them.